# Insert form values into mysql database using php and connection between html and php wont work

Tags: php, html, mysql, database-connection

here is my HTML code:

```
        <form action="OGC HR.php" method="POST">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ename" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="eid" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone:</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="ephone"size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="eemail" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Department:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="edep" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                <td>Section:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="esec" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Leave Type</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="leavetype" required>
                        <option selected> Select Leave Type</option>
                        <option value="Annual Vacation">Annual Vacation</option>
                        <option value="Emergency Leave">Emergency Leave</option>
                        <option value="Unpaid Leave">Unpaid Leave</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="fromd" type="date" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="tod" type="date" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Air Ticket Paid:</td>
                <td><input name="ticketby" value="Employee" type="radio" checked> By Employee</td>
                <td><input name="ticketby" vlaue="Company" type="radio"> By Company</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Advance Salary:</td>
                <td><input name="salary" vlaue="No" type="radio" checked> No</td>
                <td><input name="salary" value="YES" type="radio"> Yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="RESET"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$h= INSERT INTO HR       (name,id,phone,email,department,section,fromdate,todate,leave type) VALUE ('$POST_[$ename]','$POST_[$eid]','$POST_[$ephone]','$POST_[$eemail]','$POST_[$edep]','$POST_[$esec]','$POST_[$]','$POST_[$fromd]','$POST_[$tod]','$_POST[$leavetype]');
if (mysqli_query($con,$h))
{
   echo"1 record added"
}
else
{
  echo"Error in insertion the recoed:".mysqli_error();
}
mysqli_close($con);
<?
```

first how can i insert data from dropdown list and radio into the database 
and when i press submit the php code appears and no data recorded
plus i want that when the user press submit a recored store in the database and then a new page opens that have all the data recorded in the database like a history page

Comment: you have quite a few syntax errors, too many actually.

Comment: would you please let me know what are they?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Rawan.D You desperately need a book or reference on basic PHP. Your query isn't even encapsulated in quotes, it's just thrown in there randomly. The [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/) is a good place to start.

Comment: `$h= INSERT` that alone would have thrown an undefined INSERT constant error. Your code is literally stitched with errors, it's mind boggling, really.

Comment: Then `todate,leave type)` wow..... I am going over your code again; another syntax error there. They just keep on surfacing like groundhogs in springtime.

Comment: As Wile E. is holding up his [*HELP!*](http://static3.comicvine.com/uploads/square_small/0/40/166052-47219-wile-e-coyote.jpg) sign. Sorry, but there is far too much work to even "try" to salvage any of this. Edit: Best to do as @tadman said and get yourself a good reliable book on how to code and don't do any typos. I am going now; good luck.

Comment: thank you all but this is all what i learned from school ! and now they are asking me to create a whole website as final project ! I freaking out actually

Answer (score 1):

Ok to be honest with you , your code needs more and more sorting , its not secure , yes maybe its a code that you are testing something with , but first thing you should thing about is SECURITY . So be careful and its a good example to start with .

But i have Fully edited your PHP code to a new one and added a table to my database and tested the code and its working perfect .You are going to see me using ARRAY inside the execute part and that's for the security porpoises .

I have used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) . Whats PDO ? really hard to explain it but in short paragraph :

> PDO is an acronym for PHP Data Objects. PDO is a lean, consistent way
>   to access databases. This means developers can write portable code
>   much easier. PDO is not an abstraction layer like PearDB. PDO is a
>   more like a data access layer which uses a unified API (Application
>   Programming Interface).

This is the code : I will link an image to the database structure that i used in the end of my answer

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username   = "username";
        $password   = "password";
        $database  = "databasename";
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                }
            catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                }

            if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
                {
                    $name = $_POST['ename'];
                    $id = $_POST['eid'];
                    $phone = $_POST['ephone'];
                    $email = $_POST['eemail'];
                    $department= $_POST['edep'];
                    $section = $_POST['esec'];
                    $fromdate = $_POST['fromd'];
                    $todate = $_POST['tod'];
                    $leave_type = $_POST['leavetype'];
                    $ticketby = $_POST['ticketby'];
                    $salary = $_POST['salary'];

                    $Insert_data = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO HR (name,id,phone,email,department,section,fromdate,todate,leave_type,ticketby,Advance_Salary) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
                    $Insert_data->execute(array($name,$id,$phone,$email,$department,$section,$fromdate,$todate,$leave_type,$ticketby,$salary));

                    if($Insert_data)
                        {
                              echo"1 record added";
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            echo "Error in insertion the recoed";
            }
        }

    else 
    {
        echo " something wrong with the form action ";
    }


?>
```

Database Structure : https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3uN1.jpg

Hope this answer help you , but again , you have a lot to learn and good luck . let me know if the code did not work with you , cause its working perfect with me .

Edit : Forgot to add this : i edited your Html code too , this is the new code :

```
  <form action="test1.php" method="POST">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ename" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="eid" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="ephone"size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="eemail" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="edep" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                    <td>Section:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="esec" size="30" maxlength="20" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Leave Type</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="leavetype" required>
                            <option selected> Select Leave Type</option>
                            <option value="Annual Vacation">Annual Vacation</option>
                            <option value="Emergency Leave">Emergency Leave</option>
                            <option value="Unpaid Leave">Unpaid Leave</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="fromd" type="date" required>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="tod" type="date" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Air Ticket Paid:</td>
                    <td><input name="ticketby" value="Employee" type="radio" checked> By Employee</td>
                    <td><input name="ticketby" vlaue="Company" type="radio"> By Company</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Advance Salary:</td>
                    <td><input name="salary" value="No" type="radio" checked> No</td>
                    <td><input name="salary" value="YES" type="radio"> Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="RESET"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Another Edit : Could not do the part that you asked for which is (when the user press submit a recored store in the database and then a new page opens that have all the data recorded in the database like a history page ) the reason for this is because it will take sometime to style the page and then type the code , so if you needed help with that let me know , just try to read some stuff from W3SCHOOL and from this subject : PHP Select Data From MySQL .

Comment: didnt work when i press submit the code of php appears and no data stored in the database

Comment: ok thats what you should do : 

1 - Create php page called test1.php and put my first code in it . 
2 - Create HTML page call it whatever you want and put my second code in it .
3 - Make sure that the database structure is the same that i showed you .
4 - Test the code and let me know  . @Rawan.D